# Use group size (`group_size`) in `summarise` in `dplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the size of a group as part of a groupwise operation in `dplyr::summarise`.

E.g calculate the proportion of manuals by cylinder, by grouping the `cars` data by `cyl` and dividing the number of manuals by the size of the group:

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(zz = sum(am)/group_size(.))
```

But, (I think), because `group_size` is after a grouped `tbl_df` and `.` is ungrouped, this returns

> `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : basic_string::resize`

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: We marked this as a duplicate, but it has one nuance that the title doesn't communicate, and why you can't simply use `count()`/`tally()`: OP wants the fraction of group size. So use `n()` instead of `group_size(.)` in the denominator, and same numerator as current.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably can use `n()` to get the number of rows for group

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(zz = sum(am)/n())

#    cyl    zz
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1  4.00 0.727
#2  6.00 0.429
#3  8.00 0.143
```

Comment: the `length(.)` alternative doesn't work though

Comment: @rubadubdub opps sorry! removed it.

Comment: This is what `dplyr::tally()` command is for, it calls `n()`. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is just a group by `mean`

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarise(zz = mean(am))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl    zz
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4 0.727
#2     6 0.429
#3     8 0.143
```

---

If we need to use `group_size`

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl) %>% 
   nest %>%
   mutate(zz = map_dbl(data, ~ sum(.x$am)/group_size(.x))) %>%
   arrange(cyl) %>%
   select(-data)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#    cyl    zz
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4 0.727
#2     6 0.429
#3     8 0.143
```

---

Or using `do`

```
mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    do(data.frame(zz = sum(.$am)/group_size(.)))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
# Groups:   cyl [3]
#    cyl    zz
#  <dbl> <dbl>
#1     4 0.727
#2     6 0.429
#3     8 0.143
```